# passing json on home page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, json

Please excuse the noob-ish nature of this question.

I have a project in which the home page is a large google map with markers that when clicked show an infoBox containing photographs taken at the marker location.  I also have a photo#show action in which the user can see individual photos in a photos/show.html.erb view.  I've recently integrated "tweet" and "FB-like" buttons for each photo; so now it is much more likely that i'll have viewers entering my site from twitter or FB who have clicked a url like "www.photoshowisus.com/photos/34".

Now I want to change the photo#show action so that the photo and its marker are shown on the home page map rather than a separate view.

Rendering the home view from the photo#show action is not a problem (I'm not that much of a noob), but I do have two questions.  First, how does the server photo#show response render both 'pages/home' and the json for the photo requested in the id parameter?  I suppose that I could set the map up as a nested layout so that I do not have to render the home page at all, but I still need some way of passing the json object to my application.js code.

And second, how can I "grab" the json object in my application.js code?  Is there a way to get to it through an event like .ready()?  Note, I'm already good to go with my javascript routines once I have access to the json object.

Thanks in advance for hour help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about getting it through Ajax using jQuery's [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) on document-ready?

```
$(function(){
   $.getJSON("http://yourdomain.com/path/to/json", function (data){
       // Do what you like with your JSON available in the data-variable
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Christofer, yep.  That's the how I'm currently implementing the solution.  The only problem is that it requires two server round-trips.  I'm hoping that there is a solution that can render the json on the first go-round.

Comment: @chuckw I guess you could either let the server generate the JSON and store it in a JavaScript variable in the page, when the page is generated server-side. The variable could then be accessed by your JS-file (I think?) - or you could change your .js-file into a .rb-file (or what the ruby extension is), and generate the JSON and store it in a variable in the JavaScript-file prior to sending it from the server. As long as you specify `type="text/javascript"` when you load the JavaScript-file, the browser won't mind you using another file-extension.

Comment: I'm now storing the JSON in a js variable and passing it in the page, just like you suggested.  Accessing the js variable is no problem on the client-side.  It feels a little funny generating js in-line, but it does the trick!  Thanks.

Comment: @chuckw Sounds like a good choice. I agree with you, it might not be the prettiest, but it is the best way I can think of to avoid the second request.